# Cannot fix error when trying to create a map based on a list using Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to create a hashmap using an arraylist of values.

```
//Map to store collected values in    
Map<String, Boolean> stringMap = new HashMap<>();

//List of strings to use to make map
ArrayList<String> strings = getStrings();

stringMap = strings.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), new Boolean.FALSE));
```

I keep getting an error on the .collect line and I think it's related to setting each boolean value in the map to false.

I've seen tutorials on streams where this should work:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-convert-list-to-map-in-java/
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-to-map
- https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/
- https://www.amitph.com/convert-list-to-map-using-streams/

I know it is related to the boolean value. I've tried just putting `false` there or `Boolean.valueOf(FALSE)` and a number of other things to take care of this, but I keep getting errors.

Comment: Shouldn't have to say this, but please include the error message(s) in your question. What do you think `new Boolean.FALSE` does? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a `Function<>` as second parameter:

```
stringMap = strings.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), b -> Boolean.FALSE));
```